# Function communication in C

Tags: c, function, floating-point

I am having a problem with my function communication. I ask the user for a temp in Celsius and it gives it back as a Fahrenheit.Perfect! The problem is that it wont take the Fahrenheit entered by the user to give me the Celsius after that. instead it takes the previous value of Fahrenheit and it sends it to the equation "5 * (Fahrenheit - 32) / 9". So technically, I am getting both results backwards. make sense?
    thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//prototypes
float get_c      (float *celsius);
float get_f      (float *fahrenheit);
float cel_to_fah (float celsius);
float fah_to_cel (float fahrenheit);
float display_F  (float celsius, float fahrenheit);
float display_C  (float fahrenheit, float celsius);

int main (void)
{
    //variable declaration
    float celsius = 0;     //stores degree Celsius
    float fahrenheit = 0;  //stores degree Fahrenheit

    //function calls
    get_c (&celsius);
    get_f (&fahrenheit);
    //===============================
    fahrenheit = cel_to_fah (celsius);
    celsius = fah_to_cel (fahrenheit);
    //===============================
    display_F (celsius, fahrenheit);
    display_C (fahrenheit, celsius);

    return 0;
}
//===================================================================
float get_c (float *celsius)
{
    printf("Please enter a degree Celsius:    ");
    scanf("%f", celsius);

    return 0;
}//get_c

float get_f (float *fahrenheit)
{
    printf("Please enter a degree Fahrenheit: ");
    scanf("%f", fahrenheit);

    return 0;
}//get_f

//===================================================================
float cel_to_fah (float celsius)
{
    return (1.8 * celsius)  + 32;
}//cel_to_fah

float fah_to_cel (float fahrenheit)
{
    return 5 * (fahrenheit - 32) / 9;
}//fah_to_cel

//===================================================================
float display_F (float celsius, float fahrenheit)
{
    printf("====================================\n");
    printf("%.2f Celsius in Fahrenheit is:   %.2f\n", celsius,  fahrenheit);
    return fahrenheit;
}//display_F

float display_C (float fahrenheit, float celsius)
{
    printf("====================================\n");
    printf("%.2f Fahrenheit in Celsius is:   %.2f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
    printf("====================================\n");
    return celsius;
}//display_C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the converted results to other variables not to destroy the user input.

Try this:

```
int main (void)
{
    //variable declaration
    float celsius = 0;     //stores degree Celsius
    float fahrenheit = 0;  //stores degree Fahrenheit
    float celsius_converted = 0;    //stores degree Celsius converted
    float fahrenheit_converted = 0; //stores degree Fahrenheit converted

    //function calls
    get_c (&celsius);
    get_f (&fahrenheit);
    //===============================
    fahrenheit_converted = cel_to_fah (celsius);
    celsius_converted = fah_to_cel (fahrenheit);
    //===============================
    display_F (celsius, fahrenheit_converted);
    display_C (fahrenheit, celsius_converted);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MikeCAT YOU ROCK! thank you so much. My goal is to write a simple program every day so i can practice and learn step by step. Today I got stuck. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, change as the following:

```
//===============================
display_F (celsius, cel_to_fah (celsius));
display_C (fahrenheit, fah_to_cel (fahrenheit));
//===============================
```